# Jira - Removing items from Kanban board once released

Tags: jira

I've created a Kanban board to keep track of our items. Those items all have sub-tasks. So I've set the Swimlanes to Stories, so developers can easily update their sub-tasks by moving cards.

Issue is that I want to remove those items whose fix version is released. The board's Sub-Filter already takes care of this:
fixVersion in unreleasedVersions() OR fixVersion is EMPTY

However, we are only setting the fix version on the main items, not on the sub-tasks. As a result, the sub-tasks continue to be selected even if their main items are not (because the fix version is a released version). Because of this, those items remain on the board, because their sub-tasks are still selected.

How can I hide items and their sub-tasks, even if the sub-tasks are still selected?
Alternatively, if somebody sets the fix version of an item, how can I automatically update its sub-tasks with the same fix version?

Answer (score 0):

By Default Jira Kanban board is configured to track all the issue which are selected using the board filter. Work around would be to exclude subtasks in the board filter.
Change your current Kanban board filter to exclude subtasks.

For auto updating of the fix version for a subtask when parent task fix version you can try adding a script using one of the Jira supported script plugin(e.g. adaptavist Script runner).